# Use magic.mgc from another language

Tags: file, unix, go, libmagic

I'm currently working on a project which involves reading `file`'s magic files (without bindings). I'd like to know how it would be possible to read the file tests from the compiled binary `magic.mgc` directly, in another language (like Go), as I'm unsure of how its contents should be interpreted.

Comment: In principle, you can: the source of `file` is [online](https://github.com/file/file), and doesn't do anything you can't reimplement, and `man magic` describes what it's trying to do. The [text source](https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir) used to generate `magic.mgc` is also online and may be easier to parse. This is a long way from really helping you do that, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @twotwotwo. Starting out, I'd like to find a way to use the existing `.mgc` file, rather than compiling it myself. If it turns out to be impossible, though, I guess I'd have to haha.

Comment: It looks like this is the actual .mgc compiler and parser, about 70kb and 3000 lines: https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/src/apprentice.c -- not totally impossible to reverse-engineer but it looks like a pain (like, `file` is really doing lots of match types internally). There is, incidentally, a very simple sniffer in https://golang.org/src/net/http/sniff.go

Comment: I hadn't seen `sniff`! The `file` source code is complex indeed. See my answer, which I got from Christos Zoulas himself in the File mailing list. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Christos Zoulas, main contributor of file:

> If you want to use them directly you
>   need to understand the binary format (which changes over time) and load
>   it in your own data structures. [...] The code that parses the file is in apprentice.c. See [check_buffer()](https://github.com/file/file/blob/27c975960f00c7c46a3bc7429c5caad3398c2979/src/apprentice.c#L3099)
>   for the reader and apprentice_compile() for the writer.  There is
>   a 4 byte magic number, followed by a 4 byte version number followed
>   by MAGIG_SET (2) number of 4 byte counts one for each set (ascii,
>   binary) followed by an array of 'struct magic' entries, in native
>   byte format.

So that's the format one should expect! Nevertheless, it has to be parsed just like the raw files.